# Start Jekyll on boot or jekyll cronjob

Tags: ubuntu, jekyll

I'm trying to have jekyll start automatically when my server boots up. I have no idea how to do this though. I tried setting a cronjob to run every 10 minutes but it doesn't seem to be running though. Here is my crontab

```
*/10 * * * * cd /var/static-operation/jekyll-files; jekyll serve
```

My question is, how can I set jekyll to automatically start auto regeneration when my servers boots up. Or is there a crontab way for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best option might be a daemon.

I really like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) because it will auto restart.

The point of jekyll however is to only run a file server...so you might want to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Run: `bundle exec jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0  --detach`

This will serve jekyll to port 4000 of your server in background as a daemon